# How to verify a method was called if it returns no value?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to prepare a mock object using Moq to test a method (`SaveNewPersonAsync()`) which calls a LogMessage method in my Logger object. `SaveNewPersonAsync()` does not return any value (well, except the Task<> as it's async) but, as I understood from Moq tutorials, I'm supposed to verify a method's returned value. And also, the mock.Verify method always passes for me, even if I don't call the `SaveNewPersonAsync()`. How can I verify that `SaveNewPersonAsync()` and `LogMessage()` inside of it were called?

```
// Create the mock
var mock = new Mock<ILogger>();

// Configure the mock to do something
mock.Setup(x => x.LogMessage("test")).Returns(true);

// Demonstrate that the configuration works
Assert.AreEqual(true, mock.Object.LogMessage("test"));


// perform the db saving here
var dataproc = new DataProcessor(mock.Object, new UserDbMongo(), new ParsingManager());
await dataproc.SaveNewPersonAsync(GenerateJsonData("CocaColaParser"));


mock.Verify(x => x.LogMessage("test"));
// verify() passes even if I don't call the SaveNewPersonAsync() method
```

The `SaveNewPersonAsync()` method, simplified:

```
await _dbmanager.InsertUserAsync(person);
_logger.LogMessage("Saved a user to db."); // if this is not here, the test should fail
```

Comment: Since you call the method explicitly in the test `await dataproc.SaveNewPersonAsync..` why would you need to check that it was called?

Comment: ok, so I guess, I just need to check if the other method is called (LogMessage, inside the SaveNewPersonAsync)?

Answer (score 0):

> // verify() passes even if I don't call the SaveNewPersonAsync()
> method

It is because you call it here (`mock.Object.LogMessage("test")`):

```
Assert.AreEqual(true, mock.Object.LogMessage("test"));
```

The method is called so mock passes even if you don't call `SaveNewPersonAsync()`. Delete above line and you will get expected behavior.

Also, if your method does not return any value then you don't need to setup it.

The final code should be:

```
// Create the mock
var mock = new Mock<ILogger>();      

// perform the db saving here
var dataproc = new DataProcessor(mock.Object, new UserDbMongo(), new ParsingManager());
await dataproc.SaveNewPersonAsync(GenerateJsonData("CocaColaParser"));
    
mock.Verify(x => x.LogMessage("test")); // now it should behave as you expect
```